# Como extraer una columna con ciertos datos y sacar promedio en un archivo csv

Tags: python, base-de-datos, pandas, dataframe

como puedo extraer especificamente los datos que contengan una fecha especifica y posteriormente sacar promedio, lo estoy haciendo importando un archivo csv y quiero sacar el promedio solamente de un año en especifico.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se observa estan las fechas y **capacidad_base_firme** son los datos a promediar. Cualquier ayuda seria de utilidad muchas gracias.

**El data Frame quedaria algo asi** Quiero extrar todos los datos del 2016 ya que estan juntos los datos del 2016 y 2017, se encuentran en la misma columna. Simplemente solo quiero extraer el año 2016.

```
               zona  capacidad_base_firme  ...   fecha_fin  Promedio_Base
0               Sur               1.52306  ...  2016-03-31       3.540788
1            Centro               2.84902  ...  2016-03-31       3.540788
2         Occidente               1.57302  ...  2016-03-31       3.540788
3             Golfo               3.06847  ...  2016-03-31       3.540788
4             Norte               4.34706  ...  2016-03-31       3.540788
..              ...                   ...  ...         ...            ...
67            Golfo               5.22776  ...  2017-12-31       3.540788
68            Norte               6.99284  ...  2017-12-31       3.540788
69            Istmo               7.25957  ...  2017-12-31       3.540788
70         Nacional               0.21971  ...  2017-12-31       3.540788
71  Nacional con AB              -0.72323  ...  2017-12-31       3.540788

[72 rows x 11 columns]
```

Comment: `df[df["fecha_inicio"]==la_fecha_que_quieras].mean()`

Comment: Gracias por contestar @Christian ya he tratado de realizar esa operacion y me da error o simplemente no me aparece nada, No se si no estoy siendo especifico. Quiero calcular el promedio de todo el año 2016 mas no una fecha en especifico.

Comment: Bueno ahí cambia todo. Podrías poner tu dataframe como texto por favor?

Comment: Ya he actualizado la pregunta @Christian no puedo mostar todos por que son muchas filas. Se que lo puedo utilizar con `.loc` pero no estoy seguro como.

Comment: Quieres los resultados según `fecha_fin`?

Comment: Si, segun `fecha_fin` solo extraer el año 2016 dentro de esa columna.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130489/discussion-between-juan-jesus-and-christian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una de las tantas formas de hacer esto es usando `groupby` para agrupar los daos según una columna.

Primero lo que debemos de hacer es convertir la columna a un tipo de fecha y eso lo hacemos con `pd.to_datetime()`.

```py
df['fecha_fin'] = pd.to_datetime(df['fecha_fin'] )
```

Esto lo hacemos para poder acceder a propiedades de este tipo de dato y hacer un buen filtrado de datos.

Luego solo nos resta hacer `groupby` según el año.

```py
datos_2016 = df.groupby(df['fecha_fin'].dt.year).mean().loc[2016,:]
print(datos_2016)
```

Con eso realizamos el `groupby` y con `.mean()` obtenemos el promedio de los datos numéricos. Esto nos regresa un DataFrame agrupado según cada año, pero como solo nos interesa los del 2016 los escogemos con `.loc[2016,:]`. Y nos da como resultado:

```
capacidad_base_firme    2.672126
Promedio_Base           3.540788
Name: 2016, dtype: float64
```

Otra forma de hacer esto es crear una nueva columna con solo el año de la fecha, algo como

```py
# ya no conviertas la columna a fecha sino dara error
df["data_filter"] = df["fecha_fin"].apply(lambda x: x.split("-")[0])
```

y luego hacemos el filtrado y sacamos el promedio (tal y como te lo dije en mi comentario)

```py
datos_2016 = df[df["data_filter"]=="2016"].mean()
print(datos_2016)
```

Y esto dará los mismos resultados (si no lo da es por que algo hize mal D: )

Comment: Perfecto @Christian, ya he implementado los dos codigos que me haz dicho y quedo perfecto! Justo lo que buscaba y no pudiste haberlo explicado mejor, Mil Gracias!!!

Comment: de nada, es un placer ayudar ^_^